# MsChart - Rangebar marker at a specific value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts, mschart

I just can't find a way to add a marker at a specific value on a range bar MsChart.
Let's say we have a simple range bar graph with 1 serie and 1 point.  The point has 2 Y values (ex: 5-20).  How can you show a triangle marker at 15?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it have to be on the same series?  Just add a new series.  Then use `series1.Points.AddXY(5,20);` and make sure you set it to chart type Point. `series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;` and `series1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;`

Comment: You can hack your way into it: break your (5-20) range into 2 ranges, (5-15) and (15-20) and then add a marker on the (5-15) range. It will look like one single (5-20) range with a marker on 15.

Comment: @Baddack `RangeBar` and `Point` series are incompatible.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Works with Range and Column charts, but not Bar.  Maybe op can use one of them.  It might also be possible to make a second chart area on top of the first one and plot one series on each chart area.

Comment: Baddack, I have tried your option but it did not work.  I received an error message saying that i cannot mix points and rangebar.

Comment: jstreet, Nice idea.  I'll try this one and see the result.

Comment: @PhilRicher please see my sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(1, new double[] { 5, 15 });
        dp1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;
        dp1.MarkerSize = 12;
        dp1.MarkerColor = Color.Red;

        DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(1, new double[] { 15, 20 });

        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp1);
        chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp2);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfercly!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can make two chart areas and put them on top of eachother.  Make the second chartarea backcolor transparent.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);

    Series s1 = new Series();
    s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
    s1.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
    s1.Points.AddXY(1, 1);

    chart1.Series.Add(s1);

    ChartArea ca2 = new ChartArea();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca2);
    ca2.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
    ca2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    Series s2 = new Series();
    s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
    s2.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Triangle;
    s2.MarkerSize = 10;
    s2.Points.AddXY(2, 2);
    s2.ChartArea = ca2.Name;

    chart1.Series.Add(s2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Your's is good also but i went with jstreet option.

Comment: Good, I think he had a better answer.  Glad you got it working!